# How can I query a record where a varchar(MAX) column contains a specific hex value?

Tags: sql-server

When trying to convert records to xml in sql, I get the following error message:

> Msg 6841, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_missacct_upd_del, Line 58
>   FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'AltAddr' because it contains a character (0x0002)which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve
>   this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data
>   type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive.

I want to write a query to find which record has this hex value (0x0002).  I've tried something like this:

```
select * from missacct where altaddr like '%' + 0x0002 + '%'
```

Is there a way to query out this record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM missacct WHERE altaddr LIKE '%' + CHAR(0x0002) + '%'
```

or you could do

```
SELECT * FROM missacct WHERE CHARINDEX( CHAR(0x0002), altaddr ) >0
```

Comment: Also look up the NCHAR function, if CHAR doesn't give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  CHAR(0x0002) (also CHAR(2)) did the trick.

Comment: Note/beware: 0x2 (hex 2) is the same as 2 (decimal 2).  so yes they would do the same thing however...   0x077 != 77